# c - why switch couldnt catch EOF (using getchar())?

Tags: c, switch-statement, eof

```
#include "stdio.h"                                                              

int main() {                                                                    
  int wordsAmount = 0;                                                          
  for(int c = 0, inWord = 0; ((c = getchar()) != EOF) ;) {                      
    switch(c) {                                                                 
      case '\t' : inWord = 0; break;                                            
      case '\n' : inWord = 0; break;                                            
      case ' ' : inWord = 0; break;                                             
      case EOF : printf("\nwords amount: %d\n", wordsAmount); return 0;         
      default : if(inWord == 0) { wordsAmount++; inWord = 1; }                  
    }                                                                           
  }                                                                             

  return 1;                                                                     
}
```

This must count words, but it doesn't work.

Yes, if move EOF case body out from cycle, it should work, but how make it  work in `switch`?

Comment: because `((c = getchar()) != EOF)`

Comment: `for(int inWord = 0; ;) {                      
    switch(getchar()) { `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by BLUEPIXY in comment section, because of ((c = getchar()) != EOF) the for loop condition will fail at EOF, So control will not go inside of your for loop.